# Llenar una propiedad List de una clase en C# desde javascript

Tags: c#, angularjs

estoy creando una web api para ser consumida con angularjs y   tengo las siguiente clases.

```
  public class User{
public int UserID {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
public int Age {get;set;}
public List<Contacts> Contacts {get;set;}
}
public class Contact{
public int ContactID {get;set;}
public string Description{get;set;}
public string Phone {get;set;}
public int UserID {get;set} public virtual User{get;set;}
}
```

la pregunta es : Como puedo atravez de la vista con angular o JavaScript hacer referencia a la propiedad  Contacts de la clase usuario y pasarle una lista con los contactos deseados. tengo una opcion y es mandar la lista de manera independiente como un objecto aparte  y  asignarsela en el backend a la clase usuario pero esto no es lo que quiero , quiero hacer cuando envie la clase usuario osea en la misma clase usuario enviada en formato json . Agradeceria mucho que me puedan ayudar.

Mas o menos de esta forma se visualiza pero como hago atravez de JavaScript para enviar algo asi…(El array de contacts de esa forma)

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "Contacts": [
        {
            "description": "home",
            "phone": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
            "description": "fax",
            "phone": "646 555-4567"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Quizás podría cargar los contactos en un combobox al cargar la página?? Y así que el usuario elija los contactos??

Comment: la pregunta no es como cargar los datos,  la pregunta es como  enviarlos desde la vista en formato json

Comment: Osea su pregunta en concreto es como hacer un post al web api???

Comment: Si te fijas la clase User tiene una propiedad Lista llamada Contacts atravez de javascrip como puedo llenar esa propiedad junto a las otras propiedades me interesa llenar esa propiedad lista con un array . y si es una peticion Post.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Vos no vas a llenar eso, vas a mandar por post los datos y ellos llenaran esas clases con lo que recibieron. que es lo que tratas de hacer exactamente? tu problema es solo el envio de datos? como lo estas haciendo?

Comment: @beras falta código en tu pregunta. No has incluido el controller que maneja la acción hacia la api ni el `HTML` con el ng-model; de todas maneras lo que quieres hacer se soluciona mediante un select y asignando ese select al `$scope` con el mencionado `ng-model`

Comment: Pues me parece que es cuestión de  armar el json y hacer el post. No entiendo cual es el problema? Puede usar fetch para hacer el post.

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez el problema que tiene el OP es que quiere enlazar un listado de contactos al objeto user y no sabe como hacerlo =/

Comment: Pues si ese es el caso entonces puede llenar un  select html o combobox algo así que cargue los contactos ligados a ese usuario y a la hora de armar el json en el post agrega esos contactos????

Comment: debes especificar como envias los datos desde el controller del web api

Comment: Este es el problema del foro latino,  solo se pasan criticando mas no ponen atencion a la pregunta, no deberiamos actual de esa forma... tan arrogante. Asi nunca vamos a crecer...

Answer (score 0):

Lo unico que yo queria hacer era esto del lado de angular:

```
$scope.User = {};
$scope.contacts = [];

$scope.Add = function(var description, var Phone)
{
$scope.contacts.push({"Description":description,"Phone":Phone});
}

$scope.User.Contacts = $scope.Contacts; 

$http.post('Url',$scope.User}).
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

ect... de todos modos gracias.